# WSO2 ESB Collout address from Property or XPath-expression

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have the config with development and production sections. This sections contain the URLs of backends. In my inSequence i need it to Callout to these backends several times per request.

```
<config>
 <env>prod</env>
 <backend env="prod">http://localhost:1234/</backend>
 <backend env="dev">http://localhost:2345/</backend>
</config>
```

I read this config from Local Entry (as XML) and want to set Callout's URL as an Property. 
I don't want to hardcode these backends inside my code with "Switch" statement, because it's possible to use more than two environments.
Could you please show me an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read xml file in registry. Simply define property of OM type like this:

```
<property name="test" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/test.xml')" scope="default" type="OM" />
```

Then you can see the value by logging like this:

```
<log level="custom"> <property name="test.b" expression="$ctx:test//b" /> </log>
```

And in the xml file that you have put in the root of registry, you would fill it like:

```
<a>Hello<b>WSO2</b></a>
```

I have learned it from this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/retrieve-values-xml-config).

Comment: I already find out how to read such configs (I use local entries). My question was how to use these values as URL for Callout mediator. To my mind, Callout reads URL-parameter as usual string and doesn't make any XPath transformation (so it's not possible to set it as 'get-property' expression)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. According to source of Callout mediator:

[CalloutMediator.java](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/builtin/CalloutMediator.java)

It uses "To" header if URL is not specified.